# How to reference calling application from a C++ shared object

Tags: c++, openedge, shared-libraries

I have a shared object written in C++ in which its functions are called by various applications, most of which are OpenEdge (Progress).

Is there a way to determine inside the .so which program called it without sending it as a parameter from the calling program?

Comment: Why do you need to know? That might help get to the right answer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is a functionality for this in Linux, OSX and Windows.

For Linux and OSX, you're going to want to play around with the backtrace(3) function. From the Linux documentation:

> backtrace() returns a backtrace for the calling program, in the array
>          pointed to by buffer.  A backtrace is the series of currently active
>          function calls for the program.  Each item in the array pointed to by
>          buffer is of type void *, and is the return address from the
>          corresponding stack frame.

And for Windows, there's CaptureStackBackTrace. It requires XP or higher, however.

There's also a workaround called c-callstack on GitHub, if none of these work properly. Macro functions replace the return calls and give you a call-stack you can work with. Example usage would be something like this:

```
#include "c-callstack.h"

int foobar(...)
{
    if (error/exception)
        NL_RETURN(-1);

    -function body-

    NL_RETURN(0);
}
```

You can find the .h file in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Nanolat/c-callstack):

Hope these links helped! As always, you can refer to our KnowledgeBase if you feel the problem you're having/case you're testing goes beyond your .so files.

[Progress KnowledgeBase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/)

Comment: Grovelling around in a stack trace will certainly do the job, but it's fraught with all sorts of danger. I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than a debugging situation.

Comment: Agreed! I assumed we were in troubleshooting/debugging territory, it's definitely worth noting that this is bad practice outside of troubleshooting/debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can read contents of `/proc/self/exename` file.